# ≞ (measured by symbol) example usage

Tags: notation, definition, examples-counterexamples

I found this new equal sign that is named ' measured by ' (≞), and tried to find an exaple usage of it to no avail. I am a little uncertain about how to use it, and have two  hypotheses.

I think it is used to eighter $\textbf{define}$ quantities by measurments:

G≞ $6.67430\cdot 10^{-11}$m$^3$kg$^{-1}$s$^{-2}$ (definition of the gravitational constant G, based on measurments) which would be similar to ≝ or ≔

or it could simply mean assigning something a value based on measurements:

F≞ $100$N (note that this is not a definition of F. In this case it simply states that this specific force was measured to be 100N in this particular experiment, and not that the definition of this force is 100N)

I first dicovered the symbol in this list on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign

PS: would appreciate it if a moderator could edit and add the appropriate tags to this post. (I didn't really know which tags I should have applied)